# How can I get variable from Glassfish JBI Components application variables

Tags: java, glassfish, pojo, bpel, jbi

I want to get variable from for example **sun-pojo-engine**. In `bpel` I can name it like `${SomeVariableName}`.

But how can I access it in Java POJO Code?

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Ishmael! I've done some researches and I've not found any solution. I can use JNDI properties as well, but that not quite acceptable solution for me.